# Как дать Tomcat8 права на запись файлов в директории Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, сервер, tomcat

мне нужно хранить файлы загружаемые с сайта в директории /opt/cfg/** .
Пробовал следовать по [инструкции](https://salsa.debian.org/java-team/tomcat9/blob/master/debian/README.Debian) , но не помогло.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: opt/сfg/fап9eff30b-0fbe-4cb5-839e-93f92a4f0a0f.104199.text (No such file or directory)
    java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
    java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
    java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:187)
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:400)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile.transferTo(CommonsMultipartFile.java:168)
```

Как можно правильно настроить права на запись файлов за пределами папки tomcat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`opt/сfg/fап9eff30b-0fbe-4cb5-839e-93f92a4f0a0f.104199.text` это путь относительно текущей директории процесса томкат. Права здесь, скорее всего, ни при чем. Просто директорию томкат действительно не находит.

Используйте полный путь к файлу.